# jQuery Navigated between classes (same name)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to  navigated between instances of the same class.

For example..I have this:

Nav Buttons:

```
<div>Got to Next</div>
<div>Got to Prev</div>
```

The Html:

```
<div class="main">
    <div><span class="highlighted">a</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">s</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">v</span></div>
</div>
```

I tried this bet it doesn't do anything:

```
$('.main').nextAll('.highlighted').first().css("color", "red");
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You want whice you have clicked it's should be active?

Comment: `.nextAll` works with siblings (in this case of `.main`).  Your example html only has one `.main` so no siblings?  How are you calling your javascript?   From the nav buttons click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you try to accomplish, but why not using it as an list: `$(".highlighted").eq(0)`, `$(".highlighted").eq(1)`, etc.?

Maybe, for navigating, you can hold the current selected index (or whatever you try to accomplish):

```
var currentPage = 1;

... // other code

$(".highlighted").eq(currentPage).css("color", "red");
```

(See also https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/ for the `.eq()` function so select a certain index of the selector list)

Comment: How can I make it go to each next one everytime I click next?

Comment: Add an onClick eventListener to the button, which will in- or decrease the `currentPage` value?